# Chrome Extension wont run .JS on button click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

thank you in advance for the help!

Problem Statement: I am trying to create a chrome extension that allows a user to input a value in a textbox and then navigate to specific link based on the value in the textbox after hitting a submit button. At work, we have ticket numbers that I can view on a webpage. the start of the link is always the same, followed by the ticket number. For some reason, when I execute my extension, it will ask for a value, but after hitting submit it displays my js code instead of navigating to a web page. Please advise.

Below is my code, I have removed any IP related to my work:

**manifest:**

```
      {
    "name": "Getting Started Example",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Build an Extension!",
    "browser_action": {
"default_popup": "popup.html",
"default_title": "popup"},
        "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

**popup.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="width: 300px">
<input type="text" id="user_input" name="user_input"><br><br>
<button id="clickme">Run</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
function Search() {
var Y = (document.getElementById("user_input").value).trim();
  window.open("https://www.w3schools.co"+ Y);
}

document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', Search);
```

If any clarification is required, please let me know.

**EDIT**: the above code is how I got this to work. this will open a popup when the extension is clicked on and allow a user to input a value. once the run button is clicked, the value will be passed to the popup.js and open a new window. thank you to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have the `default_popup` already defined. So you cannot have a listener for `browserAction.onClicked`. More info [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked)

You can add the code you have under `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener` directly to `popup.js` i.e. add the following directly to `popup.html` and create a `popup.js`

`popup.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Some Content ..</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`:

```
var NUM = 'm';
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://google.co' + NUM}, callback);
  function callback(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Inline JavaScript will not be executed as its against CSP policy so you will have to place your script into a separate file. More info : https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the input! I appreciate it. I added your suggestions and it successfully will  open up a new page when I click on my extension. However, I am still unable to add user input. Is there a way I can do this? The documentation you sent me says that I cant have an event listener if I have a popup, but is their a way for me to set a listener up on a button?

Comment: If you just want the listener, remove the `"default_popup": "popup.html",` part

Comment: Okay, I made some tweaks and I am able to get a box to pop up and ask for input: I have another issue now. is their a way in my html for me to concat my "user_input" with the href? (updating my code in main post)

Comment: @Zin1994 show us what you tried and we can help you with the code improvement and correction. Also if your original question was answered please mark the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out :) This is all new to me so it took me a little bit to understand what you meant earlier by using the event listener. I have edited my code in my original question to show the final outcome. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Zin1994 glad to help.